# basic exercise in java

Tags: java

I have two classes A and B as follows:

```
public class A {
    private int salary = 0; 

    protected void calculate() {
        salary = 400;
    }

    protected A() {
        calculate();
    }   
}

public class B extends A {
    private int salary = 0; // (1)

    protected void calculate() {
        System.out.println("calculating salary...");
        salary = 700;   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new B().salary); // (2)  
    }
}
```

Consider line (2): I don't understand why `new B().salary` is valid because the specifier of salary in line (1) is `private`. Could you help me explain it?

Comment: Is your main method within class B or is it just the way you've laid out your code snippet?

Comment: @DoctorMick My main method is in class B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any private constructor of `B` so `new B()` is valid + the private field is accessible within same class

Comment: That's right. I think the key is that: salary can be accessible within its class.

Answer (score 5):

You can access `B.salary` because your code is executing inside the class `B`.

A common misconception of `private` (or all access modifiers, in fact) is that it acts on a per-object basis, which is not true. A `private` field is private to *the whole class*. So every instances of `B` can access the `salary` field of each other `B` object. Even `static` code in `B` can do that.

Also note that you're needlessly complicating matters by introducing the class `A`: it has no actual effect on your example, you can simply leave it out.

Answer (score 3):

`private` applies to things outside the class definition, everything inside the class definition can see them.

`main` is a (static) member of `B`, so it can see private members.

Answer (score 3):

Every class has access to its private parts.

Comment: In C++ your friends have access to your private parts. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is valid since **main** is inside the **B** class, which means all fields (even private) are visible to it.

If you move **main** to another class, it will not be valid anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Private fields can be accessed only from within the same class.  So salary can only be accessed from class B.

Since your main method is in class B, you can access it.

Answer (score 2):

salary in line 2 is referring to the salary you declared in class B, and your main method is part of class B so main can see any private stuff of B.

Answer (score 1):

Every class has access to its private members. And "salary" is in class, along with your main method. That's why main method can access "salary".

Answer (score 0):

Line 2 is the same as doing this:

```
B bObject = new B();
System.out.println(b.salary);
```

You can access the private variable because "bObject" is of type B. Now what you couldn't do is:

```
A aObject = new A();
```

aObject.bSalary;//if you changed the name of the salary variable to bSalary